# Move Windows 8.1 to beginning of disk

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, backup, gpt

I have 1TB hard disk drive where 700GB is reserved for my personal files. Remaining space is for Windows 8.1. Problem is that Windows 8.1 with their 4 partitions is at end of disk, so I can't extend space for Windows partition.

[image: 1]

I tried two partition apps, but none of these apps can't move EFI System partition, so I also can't move Reserved parition (Other) and my Windows partition. First of all I tried to create System Backup Image, but this just recover all partition to same sectors. Maybe there is some tricks that allow me to choose where recover Windows from System Backup Image?

Comment: That's a tight spot indeed that the OS (and you) have gotten into! If a reinstall is out of the question, I'd suggest some sort of partition backup utility that you can use to backup just the Windows partition and restore to the beginning of the drive. They you can run startup repair from Win8.1 Setup media and hopefully it'll do its thing and allow you to boot into the OS once more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Standard disclaimer: back up all user data before trying this, because user or software errors can and will destroy it.*

The EFI system partition can definitely be moved.  (It's identified purely by the partition type).

I'd be more worried about hitting an issue moving Windows partitions.  Like Karan, I'd want to have a Windows disc I could run Startup Repair from.  (In pre-installed Windows 8.1, the option is actually to burn a USB drive.  It will include a full reset image... it doesn't force you to use that... you don't have a large recovery partition so I assume it wouldn't work on your system, presumably you have a Windows install disc instead).

Personally I've used GParted to move partitions.  (*If* it told me I couldn't move an EFI system partition, I would look at changing its type and/or active/boot status, & then back again after the move.  I'm just that cocky).

(And in case it's not obvious: to edit these partitions you will need to be running from a boot disc.  I think GParted provide a bootable disc image, for example.  You generally shouldn't try to edit a partition while it's mounted in a running OS :).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sourcejedi! Almost forgot about partitions flags, so your answer helped me. Below I describe how I came for solution.

1. Boot from GParted Live CD and remove 'boot' flag from EFI partition. There also is one 128MB partition with 'msftres' flag, but don't remove this.
2. Boot from MiniTool Partition Wizard Bootable (you can use different app) and move Recovery partition to disk begin. I was try move EFI partition (at this time it will be a Data partition) but program wanted make changes in partition size, so I just copy this partition to disk begin and delete old one. Also copy 128MB partition and delete old one.
3. Move Windows partition to disk begin (this will take some time, on my computer this procedure spent 30 minutes).
4. Boot again from GParted Live CD and put back 'boot' flag on EFI partition (I don't know, maybe this is not needed)
5. Boot from Windows 8.1 installation disk and repair your EFI partition following this guide - http://www.itechs-systems.com/fix_corrupt_UEFI_partition.aspx

Don't forget make backup before doing this. Best solution for this is System Image Backup.