# Can I move a working OS (W10) partition nearer the beginning of disk?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

[image: Disk Layout]

I have this disk partition layout - with 2 working W10 OS's. One on the 40GB partition and one on the 400GB partition. I want to use the additional 34GB in the OS on the 40GB partition.

I dont mind reinstalling the OS on the 40GB disk, but want to keep the 400GB W10 OS intact.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You can follow by this - https://superuser.com/questions/919152/move-windows-8-1-to-beginning-of-disk/919675

Comment: You right, was a duplicate - sorry!